# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar mi usuario y contraseña de un sitio creado en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite

Hace un tiempo hice un sitio web en Django, tengo acceso a la página de PythonAnyWhere en donde tengo alojado el sitio, sin embargo, no logro recordar mi usuario y contraseña del sitio en sí, me gustaría poder recuperar el acceso.

[image: Captura de error al inicio de sesión]

NOTA:
**estoy ocupando SQLite3.**

Quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: puedes conectarte por ssh al servidor que lo aloja?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si, tengo acceso a la página de PythonAnyWhere que me facilita una shell en donde tengo alojado el sitio web.

Comment: entonces solo crea un super usuario `python manage.py createsuperuser` y con ese ingresas o le cambias el password al anterior

Answer (score 0):

Buen día:

Activa tu VirtualEnv y vas a tu proyecto y pones esto:

```
manage.py changepassword <user_name>
```

Puedes leer más en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) de Django.

O crear un nuevo usuario:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 0):

anda a la terminal y pon lo siguiente:

```
python manage.py shell
```

luego en el shell manejamos el siguiente codigo:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

indicamos cual usuario queremos restablecer datos:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(username="usuario")
```

indicamos la nueva contraseña:

```
>>> user.set_password("nuevo password")
```

y luego guardamos los cambios:

```
>>> user.save()
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).